# make two list connected each other

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

first table

- hospital  1
- school   2

second table

- texas hospital 1
- Hardvard 2
- MIT 2

this two tables are in my mySQL database.(1 and 2 are their ID numbers that tell their reletionship with each other like hardvard and MIT are schools)

In my website i have two dropdownlists. I want this...
when i click "school" in dropdownlist1 i want to see just "hardvard" and "mit" in my dropdownlist2.

this is how i fill dropdown1

```
        open opn=new open();
        rd=opn.ExecuteReader("diz" ,CommandType.StoredProcedure,null);



        while (rd.Read())
        {
         drop1.Items.Add(rd.GetString(0));


        }
```

and this is for dropdown2

```
protected void drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    open opn1 = new open();

    SqlParameter[] paramdizi = new SqlParameter[1]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    };

    paramdizi[0].Value = ????????????
    SqlDataReader rd2 = opn1.ExecuteReader("r", CommandType.StoredProcedure, paramdizi);
    while (rd2.Read())
    {
        Drop2.Items.Add(rd2.GetString(1));


    }
```

my real question is what should i write instead of ????????.   I just don't get it

Note that "diz" and "r" my sqldatabase stored prodecures are correct.

Comment: Can't you just load them all on the first page load and then sort the ddl based on the selection?

Answer (score 0):

set

```
 paramdizi[0].Value = drop1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in assuming you want the selected value of dropwdown 1 then you are looking for

```
paramadizi[0].Value = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
```